# How do you parse an Intel Hex Record with applicative functors using the haskell parsec library?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I would like to parse an Intel Hex Record with parsec using the applicative functor style.  A typical records looks like the following:

:10010000214601360121470136007EFE09D2190140

The first character is always ':', the next two characters are a hex string representing the number of bytes in the record.  The next four characters are a hex string identifying the start address of the data.  I had code like the following, but I don't know how to applicatively pass the byte count to the parser that parses the data bytes.  My non-working code looks like the following.

```
line = startOfRecord . byteCount . address . recordType . recordData . checksum
startOfRecord = char ':'
byteCount = toHexValue <$> count 2 hexDigit
address = toHexValue <$> count 4 hexDigit
recordType = toHexValue <$> count 2 hexDigit
recordData c = toHexValue <$> count c hexDigit
recordData c CharParser = count c hexDigit
checksum = toHexValue <$> count 2 hexDigit

toHexValue :: String -> Int
toHexValue = fst . head . readHex
```

Could anyone help me?  Thanks.

Comment: Slightly related: Is there a ready-to-use haskell library for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things not included in your question that you need in order to use parsec. To define things like `startOfRecord`, we need to disable the dreaded monomorphism restriction. If we want to write type signatures for anything like `startOfRecord` we also need to enable `FlexibleContexts`. We also need to import parsec, `Control.Applicative`, and `Numeric (readHex)`

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Text.Parsec
import Control.Applicative
import Numeric (readHex)
```

I'm also going to use `Word8` and `Word16` from `Data.Word` since they exactly match the types used in intel hex records.

```
import Data.Word
```

Ignoring the `recordData` for a momement, we can define how to read hex values for bytes (`Word8`) and 16 bit integer addresses (`Word16`).

```
hexWord8 :: (Stream s m Char) => ParsecT s u m Word8
hexWord8 = toHexValue <$> count 2 hexDigit

hexWord16 :: (Stream s m Char) => ParsecT s u m Word16
hexWord16 = toHexValue <$> count 4 hexDigit

toHexValue :: (Num a, Eq a) => String -> a
toHexValue = fst . head . readHex
```

This lets us define all of the pieces except for `recordData`.

```
startOfRecord = char ':'
byteCount = hexWord8
address = hexWord16
recordType = hexWord8
checksum = hexWord8
```

Leaving out `recordData`, we can now write something like your `line` in `Applicative` style. Application in `Applicative` style is written as [`<*>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) (`.` is function composition or [composition in `Category`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Category.html)).

```
line = _ <$> startOfRecord <*> byteCount <*> address <*> recordType <*> checksum
```

The compiler will tell us about the type of the hole `_`. It says

```
    Found hole `_'
      with type: Char -> Word8 -> Word16 -> Word8 -> Word8 -> b
```

If we had a function with that type, we could use it here and make a `ParserT` that reads something like a record, but still missing the `recordData`. We'll make a data type to hold all of an intel hex record except for the actual data.

```
data IntelHexRecord = IntelHexRecord Word8 Word16 Word8 {- [Word8] -} Word8
```

If we drop this into `line` (with `const` to discard the `startOfRecord`)

```
line = const IntelHexRecord <$> startOfRecord <*> byteCount <*> address <*> recordType <*> checksum
```

the compiler will tell us that the type of `line` is a parser for our pseudo-`IntelHexRecord`.

```
*> :t line
line :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m IntelHexRecord
```

This is as far as we can go with `Applicative` style. Let's define how to read the `recordData` assuming we already somehow know the `byteCount`.

```
recordData :: (Stream s m Char) => Word8 -> ParsecT s u m [Word8]
recordData c = count (fromIntegral c) hexWord8
```

We'll also modify `IntelHexRecord` to have a place to hold the data.

```
data IntelHexRecord = IntelHexRecord Word8 Word16 Word8 [Word8] Word8
```

If you have an `Applicative f`, there's no way, in general, to choose the structure based on the contents. That's the big difference between an `Applicative` and a `Monad`; a `Monad`'s bind, `(>>=) :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, allows you to choose the structure based on the contents. This is exactly what we need to do to determine how to read the `recordData` based on the result we obtained earlier by reading the `byteCount`.

The easiest way to use one bind `>>=` in the definition of `line` is to switch entirely to `Monad`ic style and `do`-notation.

```
line = do
    startOfRecord
    bc   <- byteCount
    addr <- address
    rt   <- recordType
    rd   <- recordData bc
    cs   <- checksum
    return $ IntelHexRecord bc addr rt rd cs
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding goes, the limitation of Applicative Parsers (compared with Monadic Parsers) is that you are limited to parsing *context-free* expressions.

By this I mean that decisions about how to parse at a certain point cannot depend on *values* parsed before, only on the structure (i.e. a parser failed, so we try to apply a different one).

I find that this can be explained from the operators themselves:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

For `<*>` you can see that everything takes place at the level of the values 'contained in' the Applicative whereas for `>>=` the value can be used to influence the containing structure. This is precicely what makes Monads more powerful than Applicatives.

For your Problem this means that you nedd to use a monadic parser to stick all the individual pieces together, appoximaly like this:

```
parseRecord = do
  count <- byteCount
  ...
  rData <- recordData count
  ...
  return (count,rData,...)
```